# Excel 3d map data not loading

Tags: excel, visualization, bing-maps

I have data about Hungarian addresses, cities and postal codes in Excel (Office 365) which I want to visualize with 3D Maps. Last week I could visualize similar data, but now I have a problem with that, the program doesn't show locations based on cities. Interesting thing is that if I add latitude and longitude coordinates to my table, it is perfectly working.

In addition I got a pop up message when I open 3d Maps - "3D Maps encountered an error while contacting Microsoft Bing mapping services. Functionality may be limited. (Status Code: 4)"

Do you have any idea about that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same issue here since Friday, followed by a "Can't initialized DirectX" type of error. There's been an explosion of reports of the exact same thing from many users across multiple platforms, operating systems, and types of networks, so it's an error on Microsoft's end. Hopefully they'll provide a fix soon.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that it's not something you are doing wrong.
The bad news is that it appears to a much larger issue with Excel 3D Maps that is being reported in several places.

Hopefully Microsoft will pay attention to these reports and come up with a fix quickly.